# Binding the selectedvalue of specific columns of a datagrid in XAML MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm stuck on this for a long time and hoped I would get some help here.

So I have a datagrid populated with data.
In my viewmodel class I have a Person property who has properties of ->

firstname, lastname, dateofbirth,id, etc.

Now the user can only select a row at a time in the datagrid. For the selected row, I want each column to bind to a property of the person object. Is there a way in XAML that I can do this?

Many thanks

Comment: What is the format of the data that the DataGrid is bound to?  If you are binding to some kind of List of Person objects, then it is very easy to show each Person object (really just a PersonViewModel) as a row in the DataGrid, with the different columns displaying the properties of each person.  If you elaborate a bit on what you've tried (perhaps post code), I'm sure someone can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using **SelectedItem** property of DataGrid which will directly bind the datagrid selected item to its corresponding ViewModel class property. Please see the below code snippet and please mark the answer if useful.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

//VIEW MODEL
public class ViewModel
{
    private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set { _selectedPerson = value; }
    }
    public List<Person> PersonCollection { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        PersonCollection = new List<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            PersonCollection.Add(new Person()
            {
                Id = i.ToString(),
                FirstName = "First Name " + i.ToString(),
                LastName = "Last Name " + i.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
}

//PERSON CLASS
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

In XAML
-------

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" />
    </Grid>
 </Window>
```